# Access port on server from outside

Tags: webserver

I got a debian 9 Server where I host a webpage with some applications (owncloud, gitlab, seafile).

When trying to access the page from outside I can just call the page itself but when accessing the application over the specified ports I get a timeout.

For example:

other-40.umwelt-campus.de works

other-40.umwelt-campus.de:8082 (owncloud) doesn't work

same with just the ip instead of url

Calling it on the host machine itself works fine.

Comment: you'd have to open the ports on your router. if it's a private (home) network, than just log into your router and add rules for port forwarding. if it's a uni campus network, if you're lucky, your network admin may open the ports for you.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for the fast answer. So I just hope the university will be that nice. :)